# android GPS tracker

Tags: android, android-service, android-location

Добрый день, подскажите со следующей проблемой.
Требуется написать GPS Tracker, который будет отслеживать координаты пользователя даже в если приложение закрыто, а пользователь заблокировал телефон/погасил экран и т.п.

Соответственно написал перезапускающийся сервис, но вот координаты сохраняются крайне не охотно, точнее практически уверен, что они просто не приходят. Подскажите как можно более активно тягать координаты.

Заранее спасибо

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service{
/**
 * Тэг логирования
 */
private static final String TAG = GPSTracker.class.getSimpleName();
/**
 * Парамметры гео-локации
 */
private static final long UPDATE_TIME = 2 * 1000;
//    private static final long UPDATE_TIME = AuthUtils.getGpsTrackingInterval() * 1000;
private static final int PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY = AuthUtils.getGpsTrackingAcc();
private static final long DISTANCE = AuthUtils.getGpsTrackingDist();
private final Context mContext;
/**
 * API сервесы для отправки гео данных
 */
@Inject
InternetService mInternetService;
@Inject
RitualService mService;
/**
 * значения
 */
private CompositeSubscription compositeSubscription = new CompositeSubscription();
private LocationListener mLocationListener;
private LocationManager mLocationManager;
private Location mLocation = null;

public GPSTracker() {
    mContext = RitualApplication.getAppComponent().getContext();

    RitualApplication.getAppComponent().inject(this);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (isBetterLocation(location, mLocation)) {
                mLocation = location;

                // сообщаем о новой точке локации
                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.BROADCAST_ACTION);
                intent.putExtra(HomeActivity.PARAM_LOCATION, mLocation);

                sendLocationToServer(location);
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "same location);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            if (AuthUtils.getUserStatus()) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }


        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }
    };

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    } else {
        if (mLocationManager.getAllProviders().contains(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, UPDATE_TIME, DISTANCE, mLocationListener);

        if (mLocationManager.getAllProviders().contains(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, UPDATE_TIME, DISTANCE, mLocationListener);

    }


    // Заводим таймер на следующее срабатывание если сервис включен
    BootCompletedIntentReceiver.cancelAlarm(mContext); // Отменяем все таймеры
    if (AuthUtils.getUserStatus()) {
        BootCompletedIntentReceiver.setAlarmTimer(mContext, UPDATE_TIME);
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}


protected boolean isBetterLocation(Location location, Location currentBestLocation) {
    if (currentBestLocation == null) {
        // A new location is always better than no location
        return true;
    }

    double deltaLat = Math.abs(location.getLatitude() - currentBestLocation.getLatitude());
    double deltaLng = Math.abs(location.getLongitude() - currentBestLocation.getLongitude());

    return deltaLat > 0.0000001 || deltaLng > 0.0000001;
}

private void sendLocationToServer(Location location) {
    try {
        if (location != null)
            mInternetService.execute(() -> {
                Subscription subscription = mService.getLocationSave(location)
                        .compose(Utils.applySchedulers())
                        .subscribe(aVoid -> {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "location save tracker: " + location.toString());
                                },
                                throwable -> {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "location not save tracker: " + location.toString());
                                    AuthUtils.saveLocation(location);
                                });
                compositeSubscription.add(subscription);
            }, errorMessage -> {
                Log.e(TAG, "location not save tracker: " + location.toString());
                AuthUtils.saveLocation(location);
            });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "save location error: \n" + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e(TAG, "service destroy");
    compositeSubscription.clear();
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(".services.RestartSensor");
    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}
}
```

Запуск трэкера

```
public class BootCompletedIntentReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
/**
 * Сбрасываем таймер
 *
 * @param context
 */
public static void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, BootCompletedIntentReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}

/**
 * Установка таймера
 *
 * @param context
 * @param triggerTime
 */
public static void setAlarmTimer(Context context, long triggerTime) {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, BootCompletedIntentReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerTime, pi);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "FieldCommerceGpsService");
    wl.acquire();

    if (isMyServiceRunning(context, GPSTracker.class)) {
        System.out.println("GPSTracker already running no need to start again");
    } else {
        Intent background = new Intent(context, GPSTracker.class);
        context.startService(background);
    }

    wl.release();
}

public boolean isMyServiceRunning(Context context, Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    if (services != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < services.size(); i++) {
            if ((serviceClass.getName()).equals(services.get(i).service.getClassName()) && services.get(i).pid != 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Гугловый вариант пробовали? https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Comment: @АндроидАндроид Да пробовал, координаты не приходят, когда телефон не заблокирован, в любом другом случае, сервис работает корректно. Проблема именно заставить отслеживать в выключенном состоянии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью коллеги удалось прийти к более менее внятному решению:
Manifest:

```
    <service
            android:name=".services.LocationService"
    />

    <receiver android:name=".services.BootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_TICK"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
            android:name=".services.SensorRestarterBroadcastReceiver"
            android:label="RestartGPSTracker">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=".services.RestartSensor"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".services.AlarmReceiver"/>
```

LocationService:

```
public class LocationService extends Service
    implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {
private static final String TAG = LocationService.class.getSimpleName();
/**
 * location update parameters
 */
//milliseconds
//    private static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL =30 * 1000;
private static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL = AuthUtils.getGpsTrackingInterval() * 1000;
private static final int FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL = UPDATE_INTERVAL / 2;
private static final int DISPLACEMENT_INTERVAL = AuthUtils.getGpsTrackingDist();
//meters
private static final int LOCATION_ACCURACY = AuthUtils.getGpsTrackingAcc();
/**
 * API сервесы для отправки гео данных
 */
@Inject
InternetService mInternetService;
@Inject
RitualService mService;
private GoogleApiClient client;
private Location lastLocation;
private Context context;
private CompositeSubscription compositeSubscription = new CompositeSubscription();
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private Intent intent;
private boolean isAlarm;
private boolean isBoot;

public LocationService() {
    RitualApplication.getAppComponent().inject(this);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    context = getApplicationContext();

    scheduleAlarm();
    buildGoogleApiClient();

    Log.i(TAG, "service start");
    Log.i(TAG, "FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL " + FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL);
}

private void scheduleAlarm() {
    AlarmReceiver.scheduleAlarms(context);
}

private void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (client != null) {
        client.connect();
    }

    if (intent != null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "intent is not null");

        isAlarm = intent.getBooleanExtra(AlarmReceiver.ALARM_RECEIVER_INTENT, false);
        isBoot = intent.getBooleanExtra(BootReceiver.BOOT_RECEIVER_INTENT, false);

        this.intent = intent;
        if (isAlarm) {
            sendLocationOnAlarm();
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "intent is null");
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

private void sendLocationOnAlarm() {
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(client);
    if (location != null) {
        Date date = new Date();
        if (location.getTime() == lastLocation.getTime())
            location.setTime(date.getTime());
        lastLocation = location;
        sendLocationToServer();
        Log.i(TAG, "location save " + location.toString());
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "location is not save: location = null");
    }
    scheduleAlarm();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }

    checkProvidersEnable();
    createLocationRequest();

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(client, mLocationRequest, this);
}

private void checkProvidersEnable() {
    LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    int providers = mLocationManager.getAllProviders().size();
    if (providers == 0) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}


private void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
            .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL)
            .setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT_INTERVAL)
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has suspended");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has failed");
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (isBetterLocation(location, lastLocation)) {
        lastLocation = location;

        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.BROADCAST_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra(HomeActivity.PARAM_LOCATION_LAT, lastLocation.getLatitude());
        intent.putExtra(HomeActivity.PARAM_LOCATION_LNG, lastLocation.getLongitude());

        Log.e(TAG, location.toString());
        sendLocationToServer();
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "location is not changed");
    }
}

protected boolean isBetterLocation(Location location, Location currentLocation) {
    if (currentLocation == null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "better because currentLocation == null");
        return true;
    }

    if (location.getProvider().equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
            && currentLocation.getProvider().equals(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        Log.i(TAG, "better because LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER");
        return true;
    }

    if (location.getAccuracy() < LOCATION_ACCURACY && location.getAccuracy() < currentLocation.getAccuracy()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "better because new have greater accuracy");
        return true;
    }

    if (Math.abs(location.getTime() - currentLocation.getTime()) >= 0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "better  because time to new location");
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}


private void sendLocationToServer() {
    try {
        if (lastLocation != null)
            mInternetService.execute(() -> {
                Subscription subscription = mService.getLocationSave(lastLocation)
                        .compose(Utils.applySchedulers())
                        .subscribe(aVoid -> {
                                    if (isAlarm) {
                                        AlarmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
                                    }
                                    if (isBoot) {
                                        BootReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
                                    }
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Save location on server" + lastLocation.toString());
                                },
                                throwable -> {
                                    errorSaveLocationOnServer(throwable.getMessage());
                                });

                compositeSubscription.add(subscription);
            }, errorMessage -> {
                errorSaveLocationOnServer("no internet connection");
            });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "save location error: \n" + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void errorSaveLocationOnServer(String message) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Can not save location on server \n" +
            "throwable: " + message);
    Log.i(TAG, "save location in preference");
    AuthUtils.saveLocation(lastLocation);
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (client != null && client.isConnected()) {
        client.disconnect();
    }
    Log.e(TAG, "Location service destroy");
    compositeSubscription.clear();

    //broadcast for RestarterReceiver
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(RESTART_INTENT_TAG);
    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    broadcastIntent.setAction(RESTART_INTENT_TAG);
    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    if (client != null) {
        client.connect();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

И AlarmReceiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
public static final String ALARM_RECEIVER_INTENT = "alarm_time_to_send_location";
    private static final int PERIOD = AuthUtils.getGpsTrackingInterval() / 2 * 1000;

static void scheduleAlarms(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(ALARM_RECEIVER_INTENT, true);
    setUpAlarm(context, intent, PERIOD);
}

private static void setUpAlarm(final Context context, final Intent intent, final int timeInterval) {
    final AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    final PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, timeInterval, intent, 0);
    am.cancel(pi);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        final AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo alarmClockInfo = new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(System.currentTimeMillis() + timeInterval, pi);
        am.setAlarmClock(alarmClockInfo, pi);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + timeInterval, pi);
    else
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + timeInterval, pi);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i) {
    Log.i("AlarmReceiver", "onReceive alarm");
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "FieldCommerceGpsService");
    wl.acquire();

    Intent background = new Intent(context, LocationService.class);
    background.putExtra(ALARM_RECEIVER_INTENT, true);
    startWakefulService(context, background);

    wl.release();
}
```

}